# pass parameter into a function with asp:Button

Tags: asp.net, forms, aspbutton

I'm trying to pass a parameter into a function `onClick` of an `asp:Button`

```
    <asp:Button name='ProductID' onclick="confirm_product_Click" ID="confirmitem" runat="server" Text="accept">
```

the parameter is `<%=product.ProductId %>`.

I cant use `CommandArguments` because the value is passed like plain text.

I tried with hidden input but it failed.

I also tried using form action:

```
<form method="post" action="?ProductID=<%=product.ProductId %>"> 
<asp:Button name='ProductID' onclick="confirm_product_Click" ID="confirmitem" runat="server" Text="accept">
</form>
```

but it doesn't send the value to the function.
Can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> in your aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("product.ProductId")%>' CommandName="ThisBtnClick" OnClick="MyBtnHandler" />
```

> in code behind

```
void MyBtnHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = (Button)sender;
   switch (btn.CommandName)
   {
      case "ThisBtnClick":
         DoWhatever(btn.CommandArgument.ToString());
         break;
      case "ThatBtnClick":
         DoSomethingElse(btn.CommandArgument.ToString());
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: zohaib thank you for your time. but its still doesnt work, the CommandArgument is empty: "".

Comment: if product id is in int then parse it..
 int.parse (btn.CommandArgument.ToString())
if still not work try this 
also try this <%=Eval("product.ProductId")%>

Comment: I believe that is not possible to add c# code in a asp component.
I tried this solution and I have the same result as @YanayHollander : empty

Comment: @toscanelli try to use asp:reapeater

Answer (score 0):

If it is a LinkButton...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="test" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("product.ProductId")%>' OnClick="MyBtnHandler" /> 

 protected void MyBtnHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
string ProductID = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument.ToString();
...
}
```